# DoubleClick UserControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple UserControl in  WPF . I want to call multiple Property when Doubleclick the UserControl (Lastname and Email and ...).  I use two instance of My UserControl in Main Window . I tried it- but it doesn't respond to my Doubleclick . Any ideas?

usercontrol:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="{Binding FirstName}" ></Button>
</Grid>
```

usercontrol code behind

```cs
public string FirstName
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(FirstNameProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FirstNameProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstNameProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("FirstName", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public string LastName
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(LastNameProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LastNameProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty LastNameProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("LastName", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public string Email
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(EmailProperty); }
    set { SetValue(EmailProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty EmailProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Email", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

and Main Window code behind

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1()
    {
        FirstName = "adam",
        LastName = "west",
        Email = "adamEmail@mail.com"
    };
    uc.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(showFamily);
    UserControl1 uc2 = new UserControl1()
    {
        FirstName = "james",
        LastName = "anderson",
        Email = "jamesEmail@mail.com"
    };
    uc2.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(showDetails);
    MainStackPanel.Children.Add(uc);
    MainStackPanel.Children.Add(uc2);
}

private void showDetails(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var uc = (UserControl)sender;
    if (uc.Content is Grid item)
    {
        // get item.Family
        // get item.Email
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of base UserControl class cast to concrete `UserControl1` class (and consider renaming it to something more meaningful). after cast all properties will be directly accessible:

```
var uc1 = (UserControl1)sender;
string email = uc1.Email;
```